# Get token transfer detail from transaction hash with web3js

Tags: ethereum, web3js

[image]

With web3js, how do you figure out that there was 40000 tokens transfer from the transaction's hash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a very good blog post on [Medium](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f) using the exact method you're interested in.

(Stealing from the post):

1. Retrieve the `input` data from `web3.eth.getTransaction()` This will return the hex data for the function and parameters sent in the transaction. It will look something like `0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000007adee867ea91533879d083dd47ea81f0eee3a37e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d02ab486cedbffff`.
2. The first 32 bits (0xa9059cbb) is the sha3 encoded text of the function signature.
3. Every 256 bit block after that is an argument passed in.
4. After parsing out the block corresponding to the number of tokens in the parameter list, use `web3.utils` to convert to decimal.

Comment: The first encoded text of the function signature (0xa9059cbb...) is 34 bits instead of 32.

Comment: Which function in `web3.utils` to use you convert `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d02ab486cedbffff` value into number?

Comment: @Sallu https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextonumber

Answer (score 12):

I will try to show an example how you do this:

lets take this Tx:

```
0xa543a3a7b6498bc9aec6989d99228be07855cdd23cfbf491489e8d4088b4a94c
```

This is Tx to a contract that send some amount of token to address
The received data from `web3.eth.getTransaction()` input:

```
0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000092e707288dc221d864cf4a8c710c143e97225d7d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059f37b9220158a8000
```

Now the first 34 bits represent text of the function signature (0xa9059cbb)

The next 256 bit block represent the address we want send the token to:

`00000000000000000000000092e707288dc221d864cf4a8c710c143e97225d7d`

The second block represent the amount (in hex) of tokens that were sent to the address:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059f37b9220158a8000
```

We will convert the hex to decimal with any conversion function or with this web site:
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

we will see that after the conversion we get 1659305000000000000000 
it the number of token that sent to the address.

I hope it help

[image]

Comment: how to know which rec20 token?

Comment: @wyx the `to` node contains the `token contract address`

Comment: @Tomer are you able to determine the currency used? I am subscribing to NFT sales on OpenSea where various currencies are allowed (DAI, WETH, USDC, ETH). For ETH txs I can just use the value field. But for others I'd like to know the amount of tokens and the type of token. Any suggestions?

Comment: is it possible to do the same for the following ?
https://ftmscan.com/tx/0xd3f8424c0f05efc7e628f05b8bc94e53b80a85c7c035909b4c0a2189af3074eb

Comment: @Tomer how would you decode a transaction 'more complicated' like this? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77e678921f642e327a7ad426bd7ee1db8011c31d1d61ec8991db0e87a7c4419a

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum smart contract transaction input data decoder
Uses ethereumjs-abi for decoding.
https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and what helped me was including method data among other parameters.
You can get yours in the ABI of the token you are interacting with (in your case you go to https://etherscan.io/ and find your method's description) and insert it into you transaction parameters as data, so it will look like this:
yourTransferMethod() .send({ from: senderAddress, gasPrice, data: { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, });

Don't forget to add parameters in input! If you are not sure how to do it, try to test writing the contract on https://etherscan.io/ and extracting transaction data in hex from there, as shown in the image http://joxi.ru/xAepNGqCVWqdK2. To decode hex to the data you need use https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/

I hope it works for you

Answer (score -3):

just use `web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction_address)`

```
let transaction= await web3.eth.getTransaction("0X....")
console.log(JSOM.stringlify(transaction))
```

just not forget to define your provider and your web3 object before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30540037)